# PHP $_GET url with #

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

I want to use php switch with pages. And I want to work like this

```
url.php#1 = /test.php
url.php#2 = /test2.php
```

How to do this?

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: Or you are trying to generate URLs with a `#` in the GET parameter?

Comment: I want when I open with browser url.php#1 to generate information by test.php

Comment: In that case the dup is correct.